# Inversions in hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, clustering

I'm using `heatmap.2` to cluster my data, using the centroid method for clustering and the maximum method for calculating the distance matrix:

```
library("gplots")
library("RColorBrewer")

test           <- matrix(c(0.96, 0.07, 0.97, 0.98, 
                           0.50, 0.28, 0.29, 0.77, 
                           0.08, 0.96, 0.51, 0.51, 
                           0.14, 0.19, 0.41, 0.51), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(test) <- c("Exp1","Exp2","Exp3","Exp4")
rownames(test) <- c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3", "Gene4")
test           <- as.table(test)
mat            <- data.matrix(test)

heatmap.2(mat, dendrogram="row", Rowv=TRUE, Colv=FALSE, 
          distfun=function(x) dist(x, method='maximum'),
          hclustfun=function(x) hclust(x, method='centroid'),
          xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, key=TRUE, keysize=1, trace="none", 
          density.info=c("none"), margins=c(6, 12), col=bluered)
```

This gives a heatmap with inversions in the cluster tree, which is inherent to the centroid method. A solution to avoid inversions is to use the Euclidean or the city-block distance, and indeed if you change maximum to Euclidean in the above example the inversions are gone (for reference see chapter 4.1.1 in [this link](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/manual/Hierarchical.html)).

Now as for my problem, when I use my actual data instead of this example table the inversions are still there when I change to Euclidean. The R code is exactly the same as in this example, only the data is different. When I use `cluster 3.0` and `java treeview` with the Euclidean and centroid method there are no inversions in my data as expected. So why does R give inversions? The theory and other software says it shouldn't.

***Update:*** This is an example were changing maximum to Euclidean does not fix inversions (as opposed to the above example were it did fix it)

```
library("gplots")
library("RColorBrewer")

test           <- matrix(c(0.96, 0.07, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.50, 
                           0.28, 0.29, 0.77, 0.78, 0.08, 0.96, 
                           0.51, 0.51, 0.55, 0.14, 0.19, 0.41, 
                           0.51, 0.40, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.50, 
                           0.28                               ), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(test) <- c("Exp1", "Exp2", "Exp3", "Exp4", "Exp5", "Exp6")
rownames(test) <- c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4")
test           <- as.table(test)
mat            <- data.matrix(test)

heatmap.2(mat, dendrogram="row", Rowv=TRUE, Colv=FALSE, 
          distfun=function(x) dist(x, method='maximum'),
          hclustfun=function(x) hclust(x, method='centroid'),
          xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, key=TRUE, keysize=1, trace="none", 
          density.info=c("none"), margins=c(6, 12), col=bluered)
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of here, which became apparent when I aligned your code for easier readability, is that for your updated example, the vector you use to populate the initial matrix `test` is not an even multiple of `ncol`, so presumably R is doing some recycling to fill out the matrix completely.

Answer (score 3):

Even if changing the metric might be a solution sometimes, the problem - as you noticed - is cause by the method (centroid method in your case). So the appropriate solution is to choose a different method, if this issue occurs.

**Inversions do not appear, if you use a monotonic method for clustering**

Essential monotonic hierarchical clustering methods are

- Single Linkage
- Complete Linkage
- Average Linkage
- Weighted Average Linkage
- WARD's Linkage

One can choose a method out of these depending on which suits the given problem most